# Importing Spring Framework in groovyConsole throws error

Tags: java, spring, groovy, groovy-console, spring-groovy-config

I have a very simple Groovy script:

```
import org.springframework.*;

@groovy.transform.ToString()
@Controller(name="myHomeController")
class HomeController {

    String home() {

    }
}
```

As I use the `@Controller` annotation I used the menu option:

> Script -> Import jars into classpath

But when compliging I receive the error:

```
1 compilation error:

unable to resolve class Controller ,  unable to find class for annotation
 at line: 2, column: 1
```

What is the correct way to use Spring Framework from the groovyConsole?

Comment: You rather need: `import org.springframework.stereotype.*` it this is gonna work.

Comment: It works now if I erase `name = "myHomeController"`, otherwise I receive this error: ` 'name'is not part of the annotation org.springframework.stereotype.Controller -> org.springframework.stereotype.Controller in @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
 at line: 4, column: 1

Unexpected type java.lang.Object in @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
 at line: 4, column: 18`

Comment: That's correct, `@Controller` has `value` which can be used with: `@Controller('whatever')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `@Controller` annotation you need to import:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.*
```